# How can I achieve the look of the Kali terminal in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, zsh, kali-linux, desktop-customization

I have been using kali Linux for Years but recently have switched over to Ubuntu for my daily driver

I really miss the Look and feel of Kali Linux Terminal but want to stick with Ubuntu as my daily driver.

is there anyway ay to achieve this?

I am familiar with Oh my zsh and already have it installed but miss the entire theme and feel of the Kali terminal

Picture for Reference: https://www.h4k-it.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/kali-2020-3-rele

Note: I have already tried just taking a peek at Kali .zshrc file and moving that into Ubuntu .zshrc with no luck in change

Comment: Your picture link is 404 not found

Answer (score 4):

### Kali PROMPT in Ubuntu

Open `~/.bashrc` file and search for PS1 variable and replace the 1st PS1 variable i.e this

```bash
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$'
```

with this

```bash
PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]┌──${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}(\[\033[00m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;32m\])-[\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;32m\]]\n└─\[\033[00m\]\$'
```

---

@CIPH3R

Answer (score 2):

For getting the same prompt it should be as easy as running `echo "$PS1"` on your kali machine and copying the content of the PS1 variable to your other machine.

The look of the terminal emulator, transparency etc, depends on which one you use on ubuntu.

By the way, the `bira` [OMZ](https://ohmyz.sh/) theme comes relatively close to the 2 line prompt in kali and even shows the current git branch:

```
╭─user@machine ~/some/dir ‹main●› 
╰─$
```

For an overview over all OMZ themes, have a look [here](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/themes)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the helpful replies , after looking into Bira OMZ Theme and a few other options i ultimately ended going with the Fish Command Line shell (https://fishshell.com/)

which gives me the closest feeling to kali Linux as it autocompletes and highlights the correct command blue when typed in

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve the Kali terminal look by copying the *.zshrc* file in the Kali user home directory. I pasted that file in my Ubuntu home directory, effectively overwriting the original *.zshrc* file.

Nb. The .zshrc file is a hidden file by default so you have to use *ls -a* to check if it is present. You obviously need to have the zsh shell installed

You can get the *.zshrc* from a virtual machine for a Kali Linux distro of your choice. Here is the one I used(kali linux 2021.3): https://pastebin.com/C6TxDwbw

You can do the same for the root user